# Pandas plotting: Separate legends (one bar chart, one line) for two Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting two Pandas data frames on the same figure.  One is a stacked bar plot, one is a simple x/y line plot.  There are 2-10 columns in each data frame, so 2 - 10 data sets.  How can I add two separate legends to differentiate the data?  I've seen examples if the plot type is the same, but I can't seem to make it work for two different types.

My plotting code:

```
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    df_Plot = vg.dc_dF_ChargingGroups[employee]
    df_Plot.iloc[0:plotFinish].plot.bar(title=employee, xlabel="Date", ylabel="FTE", ax=ax, stacked=True)

    df_Plot1 = vg.dc_dF_Groups[employee]
    df_Plot1.iloc[0:plotFinish].plot(ax=ax, linewidth=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html)

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

N = 15
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2023)
dti = pd.date_range('2023', periods=N, freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(1, 100, (N, 6)), index=dti, columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(60, 90, (N, 4)), index=dti, columns=list('WXYZ'))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), layout='tight')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df1.reset_index(drop=True).plot.bar(ax=ax1, rot=45, legend=True, xlabel='Date', ylabel='FTE', alpha=0.5)
df2.reset_index(drop=True).plot.line(ax=ax2, ylabel='Other', legend=True)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
ax1.legend(title='Employee', loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(title='Other', loc='upper right')
fig.suptitle('My Chart')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]